# How to add a header to a file thats created by user input

Tags: php, html, mysql, file, post

So for my program to run it needs a certain type of file. This file is called a .fasta file. This type of file has a specific type of heading. It looks like this.

```
>gi|129295|sp|P01013|OVAX_CHICK GENE X PROTEIN (OVALBUMIN-RELATED)
```

My program gets text input from a user and puts it into a file. The problem that I have is that the file just contains the string from the user. My program can't read in just a string, the file needs to have that header on the first line and the string on the second line. Is there anyway to format a file so that the user input goes onto the second line?

Here is the html and php of when the user's input is changed into a file. So the text in the text box is created into a file but I need that header on the first line! Thanks in advance.

```
 <input id="BlastSearch" type="text" name="BlastSearch" value='' />
```

php

```
<?php
$sequence = $_POST['BlastSearch'];
$file = 'uploads/new.fasta';
$current = $sequence;
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

This creates a file with the text on the first line

So basically I need the header on the first line of the file and then the user input on the second line of the file. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$header = file_get_contents($file); $string = $header . "\n" . $current; file_put_contents($file, $string);` ? (*Fetch the string from the file, which would be the header, append the user input to the newly fetched header string and put it back into the file?*)

Comment: Just add it in `$current = "HEADER STUFF\n" . $sequence;`.

Comment: if you write out an answer i can choose it

Comment: Which works? Are you making a new file every time or do you want to append a header into an already existing file?

Comment: I think I just need to add the header stuff and the new line because it is creating a new file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append the value before the user input then send it to the file.

```
<?php
$header = "Header Data Stuff\n";
$sequence = $header . $_POST['BlastSearch'];
$file = 'uploads/new.fasta';
file_put_contents($file, $sequence);
?>
```

There also didn't seem to be a need for this variable assignment so I removed it, `$current = $sequence;`.